# What is a default Username and Password for the eventstore Docker image?

Tags: docker, passwords, eventstoredb

What is a default Username and Password for the eventstore Docker image?

When I start [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/eventstore/eventstore/) image and got to the admin console in browser I am met with a window which asks for the `Username` and `Password`:

[image]

Where can I find out these credentials? Or where can I configure them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's:

- user: `admin`
- password: `changeit`

See more in https://developers.eventstore.com/server/v21.10/installation/#quick-start.

You can change it through HTTP API: https://developers.eventstore.com/clients/http-api/v5/api/#change-password